# How to filter out part of string in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that that has a column ['Busler Group'] and it contains strings such as apple, apple, mango, mango and etc. 
I need to filter out strings in the column that contain part of word such as "app" or "man".

Here is the original code:

```
    df_Fixed[~df_Fixed['Busler Group'].str.contains("Legacy")]
```

And here is the error:

```
     AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which              use 

      np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Comment: Is this a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080315/efficiently-search-for-first-character-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Demo:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
        Busler Group
0   a regular string
1           an Apple
2  Do you like Mango
3      I hate mangos
4     Newton's apple
5     another string

In [3]: search_strings = ['app','man']

In [4]: pat = '(?:{})'.format('|'.join(search_strings))

In [5]: pat
Out[5]: '(?:app|man)'

In [7]: df = df[~df['Busler Group'].str.lower().str.contains(pat)]

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
       Busler Group
0  a regular string
5    another string
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be an object type for .str to work:

```
In [11]: s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

In [12]: s1.str.contains("2")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

You can force this to work by making the column str type:

```
In [13]: s1.astype(str).str.contains("2")
Out[13]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```